# Dynamic choices in Foreignkey Field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have just started learning Django Rest Framework and trying to make a simple API using Django rest Framework.

This is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    mother_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('student_id',)


class Subject(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subject_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('subject_id',)


class Result(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    grade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3, blank=False)
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_id = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

And this is my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import *


class StudentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_id', 'name', 'father_name', 'mother_name')


class SubjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = ('subject_id', 'name')


class ResultSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = ('grade', 'student_id', 'subject_id')
```

In my "Result" model, I have two foreign keys; student_id and subject_id. This is how it looks like:

[image]

My questions is, how can I show the "name" field in the drop down menu in stead of showing "Student Object" and "Subject Object"?

I have tried with

```
STUDENT_CHOICES = [(each.student_id, each.name) for each in Student.objects.all()]
SUBJECT_CHOICES = [(each.subject_id, each.name) for each in Subject.objects.all()]
```

in the model's "choices=" field but it didn't work out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [this part](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#customizing-the-html-display) of the DRF documentation.

Basically, your Django model's own representation is used. So for example, in your `Student` model you can add `__str__` method:

```
# this is for Python 3, use __unicode__ on Python 2
def __str__(self):          
    return self.name
```

Meta options documentation for Django is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#meta-options), look for [model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#model-methods).